# htaccess Redirect ./ (dot slash) to the root of the site

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for a htaccess redirect (not rewrite) which will redirect this:

```
site.com/./everything
```

To

```
site.com/
```

So, `everything` can be anything, like `/./script.php` or `/./path/to/script.php`.

I only want to redirect if there is the `/./` slash dot slash.
How can I do this without using mod_rewrite?

Comment: why don't you want to use mod_rewrite?

Comment: If you can't use mod_rewrite, which modules can you use? There is no native support for redirects, you have to use a module.

Comment: Unfortunately `mod_rewrite` wasn't included when Apache installed so can't use it. Is there a way of doing it with the `Redirect` directive?

Comment: @John See my previous comment. Without that information we can not help you. `Redirect` is part of `mod_alias`, was that installed???

Comment: @ChrisS I am only certain that `mod_rewrite` is missing. How can I verify if `mod_alias` is there?

Comment: If you have shell access `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`. If you have mod_php or similar you can create a page with `<?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?>`.

Comment: @ChrisS thanks for the `DUMP_MODULES` tip, very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `mod_rewrite` by using `RedirectMatch` from `mod_alias` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\./(.*)$ http://site.com/
```

The `^/\./` part of the regex matches the leading dot slash and the `(.*)$` part collects everything else (if anything) until the end and throws it away.